# Prestashop Hook to Modify Order Info

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have created a carrier module which displays a list of options from which a customer can pick one.
Right now I am saving his choice to the session but I want to display his choice somewhere in the order info(I was thinking about appending it to the comment).
I dont have much experience with prestashop, if anyone has a better suggestion I would be happy to hear it.
I am thinking about something like this .. maybe?

```
/* .. */
public function hookOrderInfo( $order_info ){
    if(!empty($_SESSION['my_custom_carrier_is_selected'])){
        $order_info->comment .= ",user has picked option #1"; //or whatever, you got the idea
    }
}

/* .. */
```

Comment: I ended up using the hook - actionValidateOrder, but the session variable passed to it is empty?Anyone know why?

Comment: "I want to display his choice somewhere in the order info" do you want to show this to the customer in the checkout or do you want to show this on the order page in the backend? And did you register the hook properly in the install Method?

Comment: Yes I want his choice to show up and the backend office. And yes, I have installed the hook.

Comment: and what if you use the hook displayAdminOrder instead of actionValidateOrder () <- (which is responsible for the order creation).

Comment: You can use that hook to display your info on the order itself (assuming that's what you want). But did you create a .tpl (with html and smarty) file to show the info? because the code in the hook doesn't assign anything to smarty and it doesn't return a .tpl file

Comment: You could also try the displayAdminOrderContentShip hook